# Executable install time

Tags: c++, windows, timestamp, exe

I have an windows executable which i have installed on a machine. Is there a way or APIs to get the timestamp when the executable was installed on that machine. I am not asking the creation/modified/accessed timestamp of that exe but the time when the exe was installed on a particular machine.
Also, the exe was installed on windows system folder.

Comment: There's probably an entry in the registry.

Comment: Define "installed".

Comment: installed time means when the exe was copied on a machine.

Comment: Registry? Any idea how to find? search by exe name ? any CPP api?

Comment: `I am not asking the creation/modified/accessed timestamp of that exe` and `installed time means when the exe was copied on a machine.` ? That´s a contradiction.

Comment: I was under the impression that created Time is the time the file was originally created on the main build machine but looks like if i have build a exe at X time but copied the exe at Y time on M machine, then created time of the file on M machine will the the Y time. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3364310 "Yes" with a normal file copy on Windows, "maybe not" if it was extracted by some archiver etc. (such programs often have optional settings to preserve timestamps)

Comment: Ok perfect. I will double verify with my executable.Actually I checked the windows System32 file and none of the files got creation time same as the time i have installed the OS so thought the same applies to my exe as well but looks like windows preserve their system file time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use  `FileTimeToSystemTime()` to retrieve the date and time that a file or directory was created.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    // a file handle
    HANDLE hFile1;
    FILETIME ftCreate, ftAccess, ftWrite;
    SYSTEMTIME stUTC, stLocal, stUTC1, stLocal1, stUTC2, stLocal2;

    // a filename,  
    char fname1[ ] = "c:\\windows\\explorer.exe";

    // temporary storage for file sizes
    DWORD dwFileSize;
    DWORD dwFileType;

    // opening the existing file
    hFile1 = CreateFile(fname1,                // file to open
                    GENERIC_READ,                // open for reading
                    FILE_SHARE_READ,         // share for reading
                    NULL,                                     // default security
                    OPEN_EXISTING,               // existing file only
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // normal file
                    NULL);                                         // no attribute template

    if(hFile1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("Could not open %s file, error %d\n", fname1, GetLastError());
        return 4;
    }

    dwFileType = GetFileType(hFile1);
    dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile1, NULL);
    printf("%s size is %d bytes and file type is %d\n", fname1, dwFileSize, dwFileType);

    // retrieve the file times for the file.
     if(!GetFileTime(hFile1, &ftCreate, &ftAccess, &ftWrite)){
      printf("Something wrong lol!\n");
             return FALSE;
    }

     // convert the created time to local time.
     FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftCreate, &stUTC);
     SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &stUTC, &stLocal);

    // convert the last-access time to local time.
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftAccess, &stUTC1);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &stUTC1, &stLocal1);

    // convert the last-write time to local time.
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftWrite, &stUTC2);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &stUTC2, &stLocal2);

    // build a string showing the date and time.
    printf("\nCreated on: %02d/%02d/%d %02d:%02d\n", stLocal.wDay, stLocal.wMonth, stLocal.wYear, stLocal.wHour, stLocal.wMinute);
    printf("Last accessed: %02d/%02d/%d %02d:%02d\n", stLocal1.wDay, stLocal1.wMonth, stLocal1.wYear, stLocal1.wHour, stLocal1.wMinute);
    printf("Last written: %02d/%02d/%d %02d:%02d\n\n", stLocal2.wDay, stLocal2.wMonth, stLocal2.wYear, stLocal2.wHour, stLocal2.wMinute);

    // close the file's handle and itself
    CloseHandle(hFile1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that created Time is the time the file was originally created on the main build machine but looks like if i have build a exe at X time but copied the exe at Y time on M machine, then created time of the file on M machine will the the Y time. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, if you copy the exe to another location, then it will get a new timestamp. i've updated the code. it shows the creation date, when it was last accessed and when it was modified.